# Update a JsObject by adding an item to one of its branches holding an array of numbers

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have `JsObject` of dynamic content, which could for example look like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "viewedTaskIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

`viewedTaskIds` is an array of integers.

What I would like to do, is update this `JsObject` and add a new number (let's say `5`) to `viewTaskIds`. I want the result to be a `JsObject`.

How to do this in a Play Framework Scala application (v2.3)?

**EDIT**: In case the branch `viewedTaskIds` doesn't exist, it should be created with an array containing only the new number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a JSON transformer. In particular, you want to do an `update` on a branch.

```
val transformer = (__ \ "viewedTaskIds").json.update(
    __.read[JsArray].map(_.append(JsNumber(5)))
)
```

This will look for the branch with the array you want to update. `update` accepts a `Reads[A <: JsValue]` to transform the value. We'll read it as a `JsArray`, and then `map` it to append `JsNumber(5)`, if successful.

Then all we need to do is apply the transformer to a `JsValue`:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{
    "foo": "bar",
    "viewedTaskIds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}""")

scala> js.transform(transformer)
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"foo":"bar","viewedTaskIds":[1,2,3,4,5]},/viewedTaskIds)
```

In the case where you want to supply an empty array where the branch has errors, you could add `orElse` to the transformer and supply `Reads.pure(JsArray())` to be sure that it exists.

```
val transformer = (__ \ "viewedTaskIds").json.update(
    __.read[JsArray].orElse(Reads.pure(JsArray())).map(_.append(JsNumber(5)))
)
```

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time finding a nice solution to provide an empty array when the path doesn't exist at all. `orElse` doesn't work, because the path isn't there at the top-level of the transformer. What has worked is providing a fallback transformer. It's not very pretty, and it's crude in this form, but it works:

```
val fallback = __.json.update((__ \ "viewedTaskIds").json.put(JsArray(Seq(JsNumber(5)))))

scala> js.transform(transformer).orElse(js.transform(fallback))
res19: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"foo":"bar","viewedTaskIds":[5]},)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had been laborously working with transformers while you were writing your answer. I still have one issue: this transformer fails if the `viewedTaskIds` branch doesn't exist. I updated my question to reflect this edge case.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get `JsError(List((/viewedTaskIds,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))` when executing it with a missing branch.

Comment: @Blackbird This is the best I can come up with so far. `update` seems to not want anything to do with missing branches. If I find something better, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you've been spending on this m-z!

Comment: I hadn't seen your latest update with `json.put`. Testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a repeated operation, you should create a transformer using `update` and call it using `transform`.  You can read more about transformers [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJsonTransformers).

If this is a one-off operation, though, you might want to use the basic operations on `JsObject` and `JsArray`.  Specifically, you can add and remove key-value pairs from `JsObject` with `+` and `-`, append elements to a `JsArray` with `:+`, and merge `JsObjects` with `++`:

```
val model = Json.parse("""{ "foo": "bar", "viewedTaskIds": [1, 2, 3, 4] }""").as[JsObject]
val newIds = (model \ "viewedTaskIds").as[JsArray] :+ JsNumber(5)
val newModel = model - "viewedTaskIds" + ("viewedTaskIds" -> newIds) 
//alternative to using - and +:
val newModel = model ++ Json.obj("viewedTaskIds" -> newIds)

//one liner:
val newModel = model ++ Json.obj("viewedTaskIds" -> ((model \ "viewedTaskIds").as[Seq[Int]] :+ 5))
```

As noted in the comments, some of these operations (such as `as[Seq[Int]`) will throw exceptions if the JSON isn't formatted as expected.  Transformers are better suited to handle this kind of situation, and the techniques here are to be used cautiously.

Comment: `as[Seq[Int]]` is dangerous as it will throw an exception if `viewTaskIds` does not exist, or is not in fact a `Seq[Int]`. As will `as[JsArray]` if the path is not an array. Using a transformer (with errors) will safely return a `JsError` instead.

Comment: I totally agree that a transformer is more appropriate here.  The only purpose of this answer is to enumerate some of the possible methods and techniques for specific situations, like when you're *sure* about the structure of the JSON or playing around in the REPL.